# How come when I display JavaScript in a TextArea, it executes?

Tags: javascript, html

When there are `<script>` tags as the Textarea value, it executes the script.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Might want to phrase your question better and put sample code. The body of this question sounded like an answer "<script> hence it execute"

Comment: [It doesn't, so far as I can tell](http://jsfiddle.net/N9DRu/).

Comment: @lonesomeday seems for some it is, and for some its not. `textarea` shouldn't be behaving different for others, but for me remains dangerous when submitting a form (not auto-encoding) others on here have reported that it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185397/does-textarea-auto-encode-his-inner-html - weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode the tags:

```
<textarea>
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt/script&gt;
</textarea>
```

In PHP, you can do this with `htmlentities()`.

Comment: What's the reverse of htmlentities?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` is URL-encoding, the same as `rawurlencode()` in PHP. There is actually no native JS function to HTML-encode, though you can certainly leverage the browser's ability by making a Text node, setting its value, putting it in a container, and getting the `innerHTML`. Then again it's probably quicker to just `replace` away the `<` and `&`s. Typically prefer `htmlspecialchars()` to `htmlentities()`, as it doesn't try to encode non-ASCII characters (messing them up if you don't specify the right charset).

Comment: Wow, duh. You're right, I knew that, not sure what I was thinking. FWIW, I actuall just use `urlencode()` in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Because TextArea (`<textarea>...</textarea>`) is a node which can have inner nodes in it.  The inner nodes are still valid so the browser interprets the `script` node and runs the code.

This is a really good reason why you should always validate what the user enters and posts to the server.  If you display that input later, it can execute just like you meant to insert the script tag yourself.

To stop it you need to encode the tags `< = &lt; and > = &gt;`

A similar concept is having nodes which aren't valid html such as `<myInvalidTag><script></script></myInvalidTag>`.  The browser will still execute the code inside it as well.

Comment: Kevin - any examples on how to do this in an ASP.Net MVC app? I am using the `@HTML.TextAreaFor()` helper to bind a model property to the text area. How to I ensure this content gets encoded *before* posting my form to the server? I'm sure its super easy.