# does <textarea> auto-encode inner html?

Tags: html, textarea

I was trying to print some text between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags, but I've noticed that if I input some characters like `<` and `>`, textarea automatically converts them to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Example:

`<textarea><script></textarea>`

will produce this HTML

`<textarea>&lt;script&gt;</textarea>`

Can you explain me why this happens?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated, best regards.

Comment: "...will produce this HTML ..." How? Server-side or client-side?

Comment: The output I meant is raw html, as seen from the browser's "see html source" option, on client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't escape the contents. The HTML source remains exactly the same. It just has the capability to display the contents as is which I guess is a requirement of the `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: Thanks cherouvim for your reply. Do you know if there's a way to output `<` and `>` as they are (not as `&lt;` and `&gt;`)? I'm studying xss attacks and I was looking for a simple way to inject something like <script>alert('yeah')</script>in that textarea. I tried also with %3c and %3e, but it didn't work. Thanks again, best regards

Answer (score 0):

The dom element should have properties like this:

```
innerHTML = '&lt;script&gt;'

innerText = '<script>'
```