# Textarea content when outputted via innerHTML shows as encoded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple test here:

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('textarea#test');

        for (var i = 0, il = cells.length; i < il; i++) {
          cell = cells[i];
          cell_contents = cell.innerHTML;
          console.log(cell_contents);
        }
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="test" style="width:600px;">
    <script>
  </textarea>
</form >
```

The console.log shows:

```
&lt;script&gt;
```

I can't work out why that is? I'd like to know if the textarea contains HTML using Javascript, but whenever I check the contents of it, the HTML is always encoded.

I had a look at this SO question:
[does <textarea> auto-encode inner html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185397/does-textarea-auto-encode-inner-html)

But am none the wiser.

Comment: Try `cell.innerText` if you want it to output `<script>`. The reason innerHTML displays the encoded value is because the browser needs to know to display this as text and not render it as an actual element.

Comment: Thanks George - I tried that, it then returns no data. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript before, which says it's not supported...

Comment: You should use the `.value` of the textarea.

Comment: @squint thanks - that fixed it.

Comment: you could simply debug this by looking at the prototype chain. (**sug for future)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.value` instead.

```js
document.getElementById("b").innerText = document.getElementById("a").value
```

```html
<textarea id="a"><script></textarea>
<p id="b"></p>
```